# Access and change a variable in model class in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I want to access and change a variable already set in a model class in codeigniter.

```
CLASS m_example extends CI_Model{
var $A;
public function __construct(){
$this->A=21;
}
public function check_v()
{
return $this->A;
}
}
```

So I want to change the variable $A before calling the function check_v() in a controller.

thanks!

Comment: I hope you are aware that since 5.0 you should be using `public`, `protected` or `private` when defining variables, instead of `var`.

Comment: thanks @tereško i never took it seriously.

Comment: @p.vansia can you explain?

Comment: Actually, there is one more outdated thing, that is not present in your example, but is all over CodeIgniter's code: assigning object by reference. Use of `$CI =& get_instance()` (or similar assignments of objects by reference) is considered outdated, and in PHP 5.x will potentially cause memory leaks, because it messes with recounting. See [this lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bxxIXPc9IR8) for more information.

Comment: you are consistently flaming codeigniter and trying to hijack threads. please stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, load model:

```
$this->load->model('m_example');
```

Access it:

```
$this->m_example->a = "something";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use getter and setter methods as follows,

```
class m_example extends CI_Model{
   private $A;

   public function __construct(){
      $this->A=21;
   }

   // get the value
   public function get_v()
   {
      return $this->A;
   }

   // set the value
   public function set_v($val){
      $this->A = $val;
   }
}
```

and then,

```
$this->load->model('m_example');
$this->m_example->set_v(50);
echo $this->m_example->get_v();
```

Answer (score 0):

because you have set A in your constructor with $this->, its immediately available to any method in the model. so if $this->A is changed by another method, then check_v() will return the latest/changed version

```
function hijackA($newvalue){

$this->A = $newvalue ;
}
```

in controller

```
$this->m_example->hijackA($newvalue) ;
$a = $this->m_example->check_v() ;
```

check_v() will now return $newvalue